# How to follow a question?

Tags: support, feature-request, notifications, bookmarks

Is there an option to follow a question asked by another user? I would like to get a notification every time a new comment or answer is posted.

Comment: You can "favorite" a question. See the meta.SE FAQ [How do favorite questions work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)

Comment: I tried to post that as an answer but it autoconverted it to a comment as "trivial". Interesting.

Comment: @Glen_b Wow. Does it only happen on Meta?

Comment: I knew about the 'Favorite' feature. But it doesn't give notifications. In a day, I probably 'favorite' 10 to 20 questions. It would be nice to not have to  check all 'favorited' questions everyday for updates.

Comment: It's unfortunate it doesn't notify you, but it's something. If you get in the habit of checking it can be useful. I realize it's not exactly what you want but lots of people don't really understand favorites or realize that they can see which ones changed

Comment: @amoeba Ah, that makes sense. I don't know, it never happened to me before!

Answer (score 11):

The closest thing to this we *currently* offer is an RSS feed for every question:

[image: location of question rss feed]

You can follow the feed from there, and get notifications with whichever feed reader you have. It should be updated with edits and answers, but not comments.

Other than that, you can also favorite a question, and it'll be highlighted on [your favorite posts tab](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=favorites) anytime there are updates to it (again, comments will not count as updates).